# Open URL or file from a button in a Windows 10 toast notification

Tags: powershell, notifications, windows-10, toast

I'm creating a mockup Windows 10 toast notification using a special visualizer I got from a Windows 10 Store. Is there a way from a action button I can set a click action to open a URL or open a file or something? This is in XML in which I will run in PowerShell later.

```
        <action
            content="Edit Message (Airtable)"
            arguments="action=viewDetails&amp;contentId=351"
            activationType="foreground"/>
```

Comment: To open a file you have to create your own protocol : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785421/how-register-a-protocol-for-a-windows-toast
Example to open a URL :
`<actions>
 <action arguments="https://portal.office.com" content="Open Office Portal" activationType="protocol" />
</actions> `

Comment: same goes for files? like `file://directory/to/file.why`?